# jQuery: How to modify form field before submit

Tags: jquery

But without the ugly effect that the new value is displayed in the the form.

if i do:

```
$('#submit_button').click(function(){
   $('#field1').val('newval'); 
   $('#form1').submit(); });
```

The #field1 will display (for a split second) the new value which is kind of ugly..

Comment: It seems like you might be placing logic where you don't really want it. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the purpose / reasoning behind that specific operation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the code above, it looks like you're completely ignoring the value of the visible form element, if so why not just put a hidden form field with the name you're using, and ignore what's posted through from the text field.

Instead, if that code wasn't real and you're planning on modifying the value instead, you could use the same technique, something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="field1" id="field1" value="" />
<input type="text" name="field1_real" id="field1_real" value="" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('#submit_button').click(function() {
    var newValue = $('#field1_real').val(); // Modify me
    $('#field1').val(newValue);
    $('#form1').submit();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't account for if you hit enter in the form, though.

Comment: I believe this will work for clicking the button *or* hitting enter: `$('#form1').submit(function() { ... } );`

Comment: @StephenR It will indeed, but I'm not sure that `#submit_button` is a real submit button, hence it's submitting the form (and why I didn't respond to Matt as out of scope)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a hidden field?

```
<input type="hidden">
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a hidden field in the form to submit `newval` along with the original value?

I'm not really sure why you would try and do what you are doing.

Comment: Long story. Just patching something to work again after being broken